# ts=ref in facebook iframe_app not valid any more? (for mobile)

Tags: facebook, mobile

it seems like Facebook has just deactivated the ts=ref Feature. In the past i was able to redirect the users of my app with a Link like this, e.g.:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/sitename/123456789?v=app_359651104148454**&ref=ts**

to open the facebook app in the mobiles browser and NOT move to the mobile version of facebook (which doesn´t support Page-Tab´s)

This worked fine for me until the last few days but now suddenly it does not any more.

Does anyone else experience this problem?

Comment: Where is that feature documented? If it is documented somewhere please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue, looks like this widely used yet undocumented feature was broken just recently. Fortunately, if you specify a custom name for the page ( eg. facebook.com/mypage/ instead of facebook.com/pages/mypage/123456 ) it still works with the shorter url.